# Custom Model Binder to bind nested property values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, defaultmodelbinder

The reason I need this: In one of my controllers I want to bind all Decimal values in a different way than the rest of my application. I do not want to register a Model Binder in Global.asax (via `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());`)

I have tried deriving from the `DefaultModelBinder` class and override its `BindProperty` method, but that only works for the model instance's immediate (not nested) Decimal properties.

I have the following example to demonstrate my problem:

```
namespace ModelBinderTest.Controllers
{
    public class Model
    {
        public decimal Decimal { get; set; }
        public DecimalContainer DecimalContainer { get; set; }
    }

    public class DecimalContainer
    {
        public decimal DecimalNested { get; set; }
    }

    public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof (decimal))
            {                
                propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model,  999M);
                return;
            }

            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        }
    }

    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Model model = new Model();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(DecimalModelBinder))] Model model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

This solution only sets the `Model`'s `Decimal` property to 999, but doesn't do anything to `DecimalContainer`'s `DecimalNested` property. I realize this is because `base.BindProperty` is called in my `DecimalModelBinder`'s `BindProperty` override, but I don't know how to convince the base class to use my Model Binder when dealing with decimal properties.

Answer (score 2):

You could apply the model binder unconditionally in your `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

and then have a custom authorization filter (yes, authorization filter as it runs before the model binder) that will inject into the HttpContext some value that could later be used by the model binder:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyDecimalBinderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Items["_apply_decimal_binder_"] = true;
    }
}
```

and then in your model binder test if the HttpContext contains the custom value befoire applying it:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Items.Contains("_apply_decimal_binder_"))
        {
            // The controller action was decorated with the [MyDecimalBinder]
            // so we can proceed
            return 999M;
        }

        // fallback to the default binder
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is to decorate your controller action with the custom filter to enable the decimal binder:

```
[HttpPost]
[MyDecimalBinder]
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```