# Custom Model Binder for Decimal in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api application using asp.net mvc web api that recieve some decimal numbers in viewmodels. I would like to create a custom model binder for `decimal` type and get it working for all decimals numbers. I have a viewModel like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public decimal Factor { get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

And the front-end application can send a json with a invalid decimal number like: `457945789654987654897654987.79746579651326549876541326879854`

I would like to response with a `400 - Bad Request` error and a custom message. I tried create a custom model binder implementing the `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder` and registring on the global.asax but does not work. I would like to get it working for all decimals in my code, look what I tried:

```
public class DecimalValidatorModelBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var input = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (input != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.AttemptedValue))
        {
            if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(decimal))
            {
                decimal result;
                if (!decimal.TryParse(input.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Number, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, out result))
                {
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorHelper.GetInternalErrorList("Invalid decimal number"));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true; //base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Adding on the `Application_Start`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(decimal), new DecimalValidatorModelBinder());
```

What can I do?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried to specify the binder before the action parameter type? Put this before the parameter at the action [ModelBinder(typeof(DecimalValidatorModelBinder))]

Comment: It will validate my decimal property or my entire object on the post method? I just want to validate my decimal property in all posts.

Comment: Maybe this can solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434848/custom-model-binder-to-bind-nested-property-values

Comment: What exactly does not work? Is the model binder never invoked, doesn't the ValueProvider return a value or is it just that no value is bound to the method parameter?

Comment: I generally use the `IModelBinder` from `System.Web.Mvc`, not `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding`, and then use the following code in my Global.asax file: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalValidatorModelBinder());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Web API reads a complex type from the request body using a media-type formatter. So it doesn't go through a model binder in this case.

Comment: I was really thinking using asp.net mvc to be my api instead asp.net web api hahaah.. tank you Mike, that is what I wasn't expecting to know but it is true.

Comment: Do you know any solution I can make to `word aorund` it?

Comment: Not off hand. The media-type formatter will deserialize the request body before any model validation happens ... For JSON, you might be able to configure something on the JSON.Net serializer, to change its default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

for JSON you can create JsonConverter (in case you are sticking by default with JSON.NET:

```
public class DoubleConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(double) || objectType == typeof(double?));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Float || token.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
        {
            return token.ToObject<double>();
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            // customize this to suit your needs
            var wantedSeperator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
            var alternateSeparator = wantedSeperator == "," ? "." : ",";
            double actualValue;
            if (double.TryParse(token.ToString().Replace(alternateSeparator, wantedSeperator), NumberStyles.Any,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out actualValue))
            {
                return actualValue;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected token value: " + token.ToString());
            }

        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null && objectType == typeof(double?))
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Boolean)
        {
            return token.ToObject<bool>() ? 1 : 0;
        }
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected token type: " + token.Type.ToString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: where and how u register it?